# "Unresolved external" error when using _may_i_use_cpu_feature

Tags: c, visual-studio

Writing a C file in Visual Studio 2017 I tried to use `_may_i_use_cpu_feature` but the compiler complains it's an unresolved external.  I have `#include <immintrin.h>` and other intrinsics in the program seem to work.  Compiling options enabled include `enable intrinsic functions`

What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void main()
{
    if (_may_i_use_cpu_feature(_FEATURE_SHA)) printf("INTEL SHA ENABLED\n");
    else printf("INTEL SHA NOT ENABLED!\n");
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to re-read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), re-read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Some quick googling suggests that intrinsic is specific to Intel compilers and can't be used on others.

Comment: Ok write it up as an answer and I will give you the credit

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Microsoft does not implement *all* intrinsics that Intel does.

You can check the MSVC list here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/x86-intrinsics-list